# Formulário HTML para acesso a uma pasta do google drive

Tags: formulário, google, google-drive-api

Possuo uma pasta do google drive compartilhada porém não disponível nas busca, acessível portanto apenas com o link. Queria criar um formulário (de preferência de uma ferramenta do google) disponível para um pequeno grupo de amigos em que o usuário iria entrar com o login, senha e se possível, um captcha code (ou mecanismo similar).

Após ser submetido os dados do formulário, seria checado se existe o par usuário/senha em um código simples (detalhado mais a frente). Se existir, o usuário é direcionado para a pasta do google drive, se não volta para o formulário com uma mensagem de erro.

O código seria simples, algo mais ou menos assim (exemplo em PHP):

```
// supor que as variáveis $usuario e $senha tenham capturados do dados do form previamente
// a variável $acesso, se true, concede o acesso a rede, se falso faz retornar ao form

$acesso=false;
if ( $usuario == 'jose' && $senha = 'xxx' ) { $acesso=true; }
if ( $usuario == 'maria' && $senha = 'yyy' ) { $acesso=true; }
```

A preferência para a implementação desta solução seria nesta ordem:

1. Google forms ou outro complemento do google drive;
2. Outra ferramenta do google (não drive);
3. Ferramenta não google que direcionasse em caso de sucesso para o link da pasta

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco e tenho a impressão que isso que eu quero pode ser implantado com o [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). A questão é saber se existe um template pronto e se é fácil reconfigurá-lo para o que eu quero.